# c++ openssl EVP_PKEY_Derive_set_peer returns 0

Tags: c++, openssl, key, diffie-hellman

Using OpenSSL, I've created my Diffie-Hellman Private/Public keys and am trying to derive the shared secret key. But, the function EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer() always fails. Below is the function that should derive the key. I based the code off of the code found at https://github.com/cfairweather/ec-diffie-hellman-openssl/wiki.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
unsigned char* deriveSecretKey(key* k, const char *peerPublicKey, int peerPublicKeyLength, int *sharedSecretLength)
{
    unsigned char* sharedSecret;
    //We can reconstruct an EVP_PKEY on this side to represent the peer key by parsing their public key we received from them.
    //New memory buffer that we can allocate using OpenSSL's method
    BUF_MEM *bptr = BUF_MEM_new();
    BUF_MEM_grow(bptr, peerPublicKeyLength);
    //Create a new BIO method, again, memory
    BIO* bp = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    memcpy(bptr->data, peerPublicKey, peerPublicKeyLength);

    BIO_set_mem_buf(bp, bptr, BIO_NOCLOSE);

    k->peerkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bp, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (k->peerkey == NULL)
    {
        printf("Peer Key is null.\n");
    }

    //Memory cleanup from read/copy operation
    BIO_free(bp);
    BUF_MEM_free(bptr);

    //Now, let's derive the shared secret

    size_t secret_len = 0;

    /* Create the context for the shared secret derivation */
    if(NULL == (k->ctx_derive = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(k->privkey, NULL)))
    {
        printf("Could not create the context for the shared secret derivation\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Initialise */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_init(k->ctx_derive))
    {
        printf("Could not init derivation context\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Provide the peer public key */
    // This call fails
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(k->ctx_derive, k->peerkey))
    {
        printf("Could not set the peer key into derivation context\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Determine buffer length for shared secret */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive(k->ctx_derive, NULL, &secret_len))
    {
        printf("Could not determine buffer length for shared secret\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Create the buffer */
    if(NULL == (sharedSecret = (unsigned char*) OPENSSL_malloc(secret_len)))
    {
        printf("Could not create the sharedSecret buffer\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Dervive the shared secret */
    if(1 != (EVP_PKEY_derive(k->ctx_derive, sharedSecret, &secret_len)))
    {
        printf("Could not dervive the shared secret\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    (*sharedSecretLength) = (int)secret_len;

    // Hash the secret
    unsigned char key[] = "df2677fbc0ddd3b4e059b82207e7840fbe7fd91a64b68935135b4f42b36899c2";
    unsigned char iv[] = "17620daa95f8cd7dfef9af3a516a1970";

    int secretLength = encrypt(sharedSecret (*sharedSecretLength),key,iv,sharedSecret);

    return sharedSecret;
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: `ERR_print_error_fp(stdout)` can be very helpful.  It's probably rejecting your peer-key because you haven't told it any of the curve parameters yet, and it wants to validate that the public key is valid for the target curve.  See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman